# Triangle with midpoint

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hello how can I draw this type of triangle in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, it is a good idea to attempt to  compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: page 218 ---  https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95mertz.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Firstly a good idea is to study pgf/tikz. The bible pgfmanual is ... big so you can begin with [Graphics with TikZ](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mertz/mertz.pdf). You need to understand the styles : colors, line width and some objects like nodes, coordinates etc.

My package  `tkz-euclide` uses TikZ and I try to simplify the code for the math teachers. The last version is [here](http://altermundus.fr/includes/fichiers.php) but soon on CTAN (end of the week). I need to finish the documentation and a memo in english.

Some new macros is related to the triangle like :

example `\tkzDefSpcTriangle`

with the options :

```
 in or      incentral 
 ex or      excentral 
 extouch   
 intouch    or contact   
 centroid   or medial    
 orthic     or   ortho     
 feuerbach 
 euler     
 tangential
 name
```

With name you can assign a name to the new coordinate. The definition of each option come from [mathworld.wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com)

Now you have also `\tkzDefTriangleCenter`with

```
  ortho    
  centroid   
  circum     
  in        
  ex         
  euler    
  symmedian  
  lemoine    
  grebe      
  spieker    
  gergonne   
  nagel     
  mittenpunk
  feuerbach
```

Macros for circles ... etc.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0 /A,6/0/B,0.8/4/C}
 \tkzDefSpcTriangle[centroid,name=M](A,B,C){a,b,c}
 \tkzDefTriangleCenter[centroid](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{G}

 \tkzDrawPolygon[blue](A,B,C)
 \tkzDrawPolygon[red](Ma,Mb,Mc)
 \tkzDrawPoints[red](A,B,C)
 \tkzDrawPoints[blue](Ma,Mb,Mc)
 \tkzAutoLabelPoints[center=G,blue,dist=.1](A,B,C)
 \tkzAutoLabelPoints[center=G,red](Ma,Mb,Mc)

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! This is to give you a start. Note that there are *many* related posts. But to get started you may just read section **13.5 Coordinate Calculations** of the pgf manual (v 3.1.5).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) coordinate[label=left:$A$] (A) --
 (3,3) coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B)  --
 (5,0) coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C) -- cycle
 (A) -- ($(B)!0.5!(C)$) coordinate[label=right:$A_1$](A1) 
 (B)--($(A)!0.5!(C)$) coordinate[label=below:$B_1$](B1)
 (intersection cs:first line={(A)--(A1)},
 second line={(B)--(B1)}) coordinate[label=below right:$M$] (M);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`PsTricks` also one of a nice utility to draw this kind of images, and the codes are:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[CodeFigColor=.,shortput=nab](8,6)
    \pstTriangle(0,6){A}(8,0){B}(3,0){C}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A|0,0)(C)
    \pstProjection[CodeFig]{B}{C}{A}[P]
    \psset{MarkAngleRadius=.5,LabelSep=1,MarkAngle=90}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHash]{C}{A}{B}{$\alpha$}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHashh]{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHashhh]{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}
    \psset{linestyle=none}
    \pcline(A)(B)^{$c$}
    \pcline(A)(C)_{$b$}
    \pcline(C)(B)_{$a$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

PS: Courtesy to `kiss my armpit` suggestion...